# How to set Chef Cookbook Dependencies in metadata file

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

The issue I have is that there are cookbooks that exist on github with the same name as a cookbook on the chef cookbook site (monit is the cookbook). I am write a cookbook and want to use the github version, however berkshelf pulls the version from the chef site when I include the metadata keyword in my Berksfile. I tried to override this in the Berksfile. here is the content of mt berksfile:

```
site :opscode
cookbook "monit" , git: "https://github.com/phlipper/chef-monit.git"

metadata
```

Comment: Looks like all I needed to do was remove my Berksfile.lock and move the monit line after the metadata line. Now when I "vagrant up" it pulls the version from github and all things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Berkshelf.

Refs:

- https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf/issues/970
- https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf/issues/958
- https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf/issues/952

Answer (score 0):

Add the cookbook in metadata file in last and name of cookbook should be in single quotes , below is the example

depends 'test'

Comment: if you want to add depedency cookbook version for particular version , you can mention it depends 'test', '= 1.0.0'